# Actionscript 3 message box?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, modal-dialog, messagebox

I need to show a modal confirmation dialog with yes no buttons and get the results what the user has clicked in ActionScript 3

ok save diaglog does not who up when  exit is called the application just exits.

```
 Alert.show("Do you realy want to delete", "My Title", 3,null,
        function alertClickHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
              if (event.detail==Alert.YES)
              {
                 canvas.save();     // does not popup when next line is present                        
                 exit();

              }
       } );
```

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: why do you use exit()? Take it off

Comment: i need to ext after the image is save shouldn't thats how the save and exit functionality suppose to work.

Comment: Sorry, but it's really difficult to understand you. So, what's the problem now? Do you want your app exit?

Comment: i need to implement the save an exit functionality but as i call the save method, the Filereference and all the stuff, the save dialog does not appear instead the app just exits and when removing the exit() function the save functionality just works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls in Actionscript are sometimes asynchronous.

Specially calls to file saves and all.

What you should really do is :

```
Alert.show("Do you realy want to delete", "My Title", 3,null,
        function alertClickHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
              if (event.detail==Alert.YES)
              {
                 canvas.save(true);     // does not popup when next line is present                        
                 exit();

              }
       } );
```

Modify the save function as follows:

```
public function save(exitAfterSave:boolean):void
{
    //do whatever you need to do to save the file
    if(exitAfterSave)
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the example for an Alert box:

```
Alert.show("Do you realy want to delete", "My Title", 3,null,
        function alertClickHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
                        if (event.detail==Alert.YES)
                        {
                                //do stuff if clicked yes       
                        }
       } );
```

Comment: Adnan i had edited the question included ur answer but the the show dialog doesn't show up when the exit() is called the app just exists.